# Winding number of antipodal function $f: S^1\to S^1$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Take a continuous, antipodal function $f: S^1\to S^1$ where antipodal means $$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ for all $x\in S^1$. How to prove that the winding number of $f$ is not equal to zero? This is my intuition but I failed to find a proof.

By $S^1$ I mean a circle in the plane $\bf C$ around zero. By winding number I mean the winding number of the graph of $f$ in the plane around zero. It is an integer representing the total number of times that the graph of $f$ travels counterclockwise around zero.

I would be interested in both an analytical proof as well as an algebraic topology proof (if this exists).

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: I want to thank the people who gave comments and asked questions to improve the quality of the question. I tried to reflect them in this updated version of the question. Thank you also for the fixed point answer.

Comment: Why should it be $<0?$ Think of $f(z)=z.$

Comment: You should tell us which defiinition of  winding number is used.

Comment: Do you know the winding number of reflection across an axis?

Comment: This is tagged "fixed-point-theroems", so using winding numbers argue (a) if $f$ has no fixed points, then it has degree 1 and (b) if it has fixed points $\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ with $\gamma(t):=\exp\big(2\pi i \cdot t\big)\cdot \alpha$ where $\alpha \in S^1$ such that $f\Big(\gamma\big(0\big)\Big)=\gamma\big(0\big)\implies f\Big(\gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)\Big)=\gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)=-\gamma\big(0\big)$ and $n\big(f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]},0\big)= n\big(f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0.5,1]},0\big)$ implying $f$ has odd degree. E.g.  consider $z\mapsto z^k$ for odd k.

Comment: I use $f\Big(\gamma\big(0\big)\Big)=\gamma(0)=\alpha$ i.e.$\alpha$ is a rotation so that the 'starting point' of the curve is a fixed point under $f$. Now $\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]}$ refers to the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[0,0.5]$ so $n\big(f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]},0\big)$ refers to the winding number around zero of this non-closed curve [for an exact definition ref e.g. chp 7 of Beardon's *Complex Analysis* or chapter 3 of Fulton's *Algebraic Topology* or w/ extremely minor change the 2nd half of Steenrod & Chinn's book].

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks a lot, this is super helpful, thank you for clarifying. I will look up these references. Because I was thinking that your last equation (winding number of $\gamma$ in the first half interval equals winding number of $\gamma$ in the second half interval would actually imply the total winding number is a multiple of $2$ and hence even.

Comment: Close.  What it actually implies is $2\cdot n\big(f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]},0\big)=n\big(f\circ\gamma,0\big)\in \mathbb Z$  but being antipode preserving you know $f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]}$ is in $S^1$ but is not a closed curve so  $n\big(f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]},0\big)\not \in \mathbb Z\implies 2\cdot n\big(f\circ\gamma_{\big\vert [0,0.5]},0\big)$ is odd.  [The fixed points aren't really needed, they just simplify the visualization a bit.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great comments - completely clear now. This last step of your argument is really smart. If you wish to paste your comments as answer, I will definitely accept this answer